# How to add an id to the menu item programmatically in android

Tags: android, menu, menuitem, navigationview

I want to add a id name to get to change the fragments with onNavigationItemSelected, but I can not add an id programmatically.
I need something like **"setId ()"** as in the code shown

```
menu.add("menu_name");
menu.getItem(i).setId("nav_item"+(i));
menu.getItem(i).setIcon(idIcon);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `Menu.java` there is this signature of the `add()` method:

> ```
> /**
>  * Add a new item to the menu. This item displays the given title for its
>  * label.
>  * 
>  * @param groupId The group identifier that this item should be part of.
>  *        This can be used to define groups of items for batch state
>  *        changes. Normally use {@link #NONE} if an item should not be in a
>  *        group.
>  * @param itemId Unique item ID. Use {@link #NONE} if you do not need a
>  *        unique ID.
>  * @param order The order for the item. Use {@link #NONE} if you do not care
>  *        about the order. See {@link MenuItem#getOrder()}.
>  * @param title The text to display for the item.
>  * @return The newly added menu item.
>  */
> ```

```
public MenuItem add(int groupId, int itemId, int order, CharSequence title);
```

Use it like this:

```
int newId = 100;
MenuItem newItem = menu.add(0, newId, 0, "New Item");
```

It returns the new menu item.

Comment: Can this id be any number? Or should I worry about something?

Comment: You're probably going to use it to check which menu item was clicked. So you must make sure that this id is not the same among the other menu items ids.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [add (int groupId, 
                int itemId, 
                int order, 
                CharSequence title)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu#add(int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence)), the second parameter is the id of menu item.
for example:

```
menu.add(0, 2, 0, "menu name");// 2 is the id value.
```